# My SQL Join more than 5 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I Have a table named 'quote' and it has following fields..

```
category_id
subcategory_id
country_id
region_id
rural_id
notes
sender_uid
receiver_uid 
created_timestamp
is_quote_active
```

Also I have 'category','subcategory','country','region','rural' and 'user' tables.
I need an SQL query to retrive data as follows..

```
category_name (from 'category' table)
subcategory_name (from 'subcategory' table)
country_name (from 'country' table)
region_name (from 'region' table)
rural_name (from 'rural' table)
notes 
sender_name (from 'user' table)
receiver_name (from 'user' table)
created_timestamp
is_quote_active
```

in fact I need to get names instead of IDs.
I'm looking for the most effecient way..

Thanks

Comment: So what is the question? More than 5 tables are joined exactly the same as 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT  quote.quote_id, quote.notes, quote.is_quote_active, quote.created_timestamp, category.category_name, subcategory.subcategory_name, rural.rural_name, region.region_name, country.country_name, s.name AS sname, r.name AS rname 
  FROM quote
         LEFT JOIN category ON quote.category_id = category.category_id
   LEFT JOIN subcategory ON quote.subcategory_id = subcategory.subcategory_id
   LEFT JOIN country ON quote.country_id = country.country_id
   LEFT JOIN region ON quote.region_id = region.region_id
   LEFT JOIN rural ON quote.rural_id = rural.rural_id
   LEFT JOIN user s ON quote.sender_uid = s.uid 
   LEFT JOIN user r ON quote.receiver_uid = r.uid
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to Join All these table

For example,

```
SELECT CN.category_name ,SC.subcategory_name ,CO.country_name ,R.region_name ,RE.region_name ,U.sender_name ,U.receiver_name 
From category Left JOIN subcategory ON ...
              Left JOIN country ON..
              Left JOIN region ON..
              Left JOIN rural ON..
              Left JOIN User ON..
Where 'Your condition here'
```